# How to close a window without the application quitting?

Tags: macos, shortcut

The OS X menu allows exit, minimize and maximize:

[image]  
I know the following shortcuts:

Exit:      <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
Minimize:  <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
Maximize:  ?

When I use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to exit the behavior differs from clicking the red button.  I want the UI to close and the application to remain running.  Instead, the application exits entirely.

How can I accomplish this with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: sounds like the answer to your question is command + W  for most applications... I think that should be marked as the right answer

Comment: @GarrettSimpson - Why is + W better than + h?  I've been using + h for several years now with success.  I can't think of a reason to switch to +W.  And I don't see a clear explanation in any answer.

Comment: i said that because command + h hides all the windows for a program, but command + W closes the open window, which is what happens when you press the red button.  You can try it out yourself with multiple windows in chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always have the option to *hide* the active program. When the application in question is *active* (in front of all others) there are 2 options:

1. option <kbd>⌥</kbd>+click on the Desktop
2. command <kbd>⌘</kbd>+h

The first option always works or at least I can't think of any exceptions this minute. The second is supported by *most* applications.

In either case:

1. Your session will be preserved.
2. Neither will cause these windows to be displayed in the Dock where the minimized programs are located.
3. You'll need both hands.

So, if you're scanning eBay at work, you'll likely only look suspicious. But, if you lean into it and use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> (command+tab) PLUS <kbd>⌘</kbd>+h in succession, you might actually look like you're doing work.

But, in the event you're asked to bring your browser back to the forefront you'll be busted. It will display exactly what you were looking at when you hid it.

You can imagine how I know this `:-)`

Comment: I experienced much success with ⌘+h!

Comment: Glad to pass it along  :-)

Answer (score 18):

Typically, an application will offer a way to both close the UI and quit the application. These are usually standardized to <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the UI/window and <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the application.

Some applications will still quit entirely when you use <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, such as Preview. You can usually rely on this shortcut to close the window without quitting, however.

I should also point out that the red button in the top left does not "quit" the application as you mentioned in the question body. It will close the window (just like <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).

Comment: In tabbed apps `Cmd+W` closes the current tab. In such cases `Cmd+Shift+W` usually closes the current window.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will close the application's window, leaving the application running in the background.

There are a few exceptions to this (iPhoto, etc) but the majority of applications will have this behavior.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because, if I open activity monitor and App Store, and then use cmd+w to 'close' app store (or the red cross), then it still disappears from Activity Monitor, leading me to think that it has been quit.

Comment: tabs only ... two windows each with tabs ... is not the same

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>command ⌘+H</kbd> to hide one entire application. Only the dock item will be visible. However, it's better to have an app, that uses a menubar item ("Menubar App") and allows you to completely hide the dock item while running.

Comment: jesus what an answer .. did you read the question?

Answer (score 3):

**'Alt F4' on Mac**

I recently started working with Mac and this was the first thing i researched. Its surprising that no one knows of this command even tho its in the official 'docs'.

- cmd + shift + w --> closes window with its tabs

[apple shortcut page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343)

Comment: Best answer for chrome, but still not equivalent to clicking on the cross for all apps

Comment: well its a shortcut ;-)
you probably want to do this when you have to instantly close all tabs in that window without aiming the mouse to the close button.

Comment: The question is how can you have the same behavior as clicking on the red button with a shortcut. Cmd+Shift+W is the exact answer for chrome, but mot app won't support this shortcut. I am still looking for a shortcut that has this behavior in all apps

Comment: thats not for non tab applications

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of application

If the application is multi-document (.g Safari, Preview)  i.e. can have several different documents open in several windows then <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will close the current window and leave the application running (until possible it is shut down if the OS needs more resources)

If the application has just one window e.g. App Store, System preferences then closing the window will also close the app. Thus <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> do the same

Answer (score 0):

I've found it annoying that none of the keyboard shortcuts seem to be quite the same as window close.  I ending up binding hyper+w to `hs.window.focusedWindow():close()` in Hammerspoon and that works